# 802.1x wired password Authentication loop in ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Tags: 20.04, network-manager, password, authentication, wired

I am student in a university. When I try to connect to the LAN using 802.1x password in ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS version(kernel 5.4.0-58-generic) it pops in a loop asking me that the authentication requires a password. I tried some things in a post about the same issue in ubuntu 16.04 but they don't work. Any help would be great.

Comment: Have you tried setting up the connection in Settings > Network > Security? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: I have tried setting 802.1x password through settings, network manager and nm-uti none of them worked. It just keeps popping in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue after changing password. Got it fixed by:

1. disabling 802.1x
2. connecting to ethernet
3. enabling the security again and typing in username and password.